# CTCellularPlanProvisioning.supportsCellularPlan() always returns false

Tags: ios, telephony, core-telephony

I've been running some experiments logging out the results of some telephony classes such as CTTelephonyNetworkInfo and CTSubscribers and CTCellularPlanProvisioning to look at their output for various configurations of phones (such as with a physical sim, with an esim, with two esims, with a physical and sim).
One thing I noticed what that CTCellularPlanProvisioning.supportsCellularPlan() always returns false.
It does this for eSim enabled phone without an eSim cellular plan, if an active plan is then added to the eSim for the phone, the API still returns false.
Yet the documentation for it says "Indicates whether the device supports eSIM."
Why does it never return true?

My app has the com.apple.CommCenter.fine-grained/public-subscriber-info entitlement.

Comment: Is that an app developed using a Developer or an Enterprise Apple account? Did you get eSIM entitlement from Apple and selected it when generating the Provisioning Profile?

Comment: @johann, its a developer account and the entitlement is granted by Apple and is within the provisioning profile (other functionality granted by this entitlment works which otherwise wouldn't, so its not an issue with the entitlement/profile)

Comment: @Gruntcakes did you ever find out the solution? I'm suspecting that accessing this API requires eSIM entitlement from Apple, which is granted by a special request and usually takes months to fulfil, but i'm unsure if this is the case. Were you able to determine why it always returns false in your case? Thanks!

Comment: @grago no I never found out why this always returns false. What do you mean by the eSim requirements? The app has the com.apple.CommCenter.fine-grained requirement if that's what you mean (which permits the app to, for example, programmatically detect the phone number). If you don't mean that entitlement, what is the exact name of the eSim entitlement and what does it permit an app to do that com.apple.CommCenter.fine-grained does not?

Comment: @Gruntcakes i think it's called LPA access and it must be explicitly requested to Apple. The request form is this: https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/esim-access-entitlement This allows you to activate esim data plans without having to scan a QR code, but i suspect that it also allows to determine if the device has eSIM capabilities (by calling CTCellularPlanProvisioning.supportsCellularPlan() which currently returns false no matter what)

Comment: @Gruntcakes, did you find a solution to this problem without using "esim-access-entitlement" ?

Comment: @sergey_s no I didn't